# Запятая перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед тире в предложении: "Льет ли теплый дождь, падает ли снег - я в подъезде против дома твоего стою".

Comment: Думаю, что сочетание двух знаков подряд нужно исключить из употребления именно в случае запятая-тире по причине разного толкования и невозможности дать ясный, розенталевский ответ. Такое "расширительное" употребление знака тире перестанет быть предметом диссертационных работ по лингвистике.

Comment: Нужно упрощать русскую пунктуацию, а не городить новые правила и исключения из них, точно.

Comment: >Думаю, что сочетание двух знаков подряд нужно исключить из употребления именно в случае запятая-тире   

Могу отчасти согласиться, ибо вопрос действительно непростой, я его тут несколько раз поднимал, но исчрпывающего ответа так и не получил. Я имею в виду полное правило, когда бы запятая "поглощалась" тире, обычно приводят только частные случаи без гаратнии полноты списка. 

НО!!!
Это все не про наш случай. Здесь-то все предельно ясно. Тире и запятая это *альтернативные* занки, ставявящиеся по принципу "или-или" на одном основании. Причин для обоих знаков нет никаких.

Answer (score 5):

Я считаю, что в подобном предложении нужна либо запятая (отделяет придаточное от главного), либо тире (отделяет придаточное от главного, одновременно обозначая интонационную паузу). В полном соответствии с Розенталем. **"При интонационном подчеркивании придаточные изъяснительные, реже условные и уступительные, стоящие впереди главного предложения, могут отделяться от него не запятой, а тире"**

Comment: §113. Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении и в периоде

Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении ставятся в качестве единого знака:
1)перед главным предложением, которому предшествует ряд однородных придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение сложного целого на две части, например: Кто виноват из них, кто прав, – судить не нам (Крылов); Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал, – мы этого не знаем (Добролюбов);

Разве в примере не это?

Comment: "Манипулируем ли мы правилами, или правила манипулируют нами - совершенно неважно; важен всеобщий процесс вовлеченности в вопросы русской грамоты : как все-таки правильно?! "

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно согласен с [@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f). Никогда не слышал, чтобы при таких простых конструкциях совмещали запятую и тире, здесь обычное отделение придаточной от главной.

Скажите, [[@тиран](/users/1448/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD)](/users/1448/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD), что за источник (§113) вы цитируете?

[@grumant](/users/1349/grumant), ваше предложение написано правильно, хотя можно поспорить насчет запятой перед *"или"*. Я понимаю, какой логикой пользовался автор: повторяющийся союз *"ли"*, который во второй части трансформировался в *"или"*, но я бы избегал таких конструкций. В вашем предложении тире оправдано интонационно, он отделяет придаточные от главной. Всё просто.

[[@тиран](/users/1448/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD)](/users/1448/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD) хочу сказать, что полное исключение комбинации "запятая-тире" породит кучу ерунды. Например: *"Человек, не признающий авторитетов, — нигилист"*. Без запятой определение будет не обособленно, будет казаться, что слово *"нигилист"* не сказуемое, а часть определения. Могу много таких примеров привести.

Comment: [Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ М.: ЧеРо, 1999](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/20.htm )

Answer (score 0):

[Валентин](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/981/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD), если Вы считаете, что тире недостаточно в:
**Человек, не признающий авторитетов, — нигилист.** И что без запятой определение будет не обособленно, будет казаться, что слово "нигилист" не сказуемое, а часть определения, то в **Нигилист — человек, не признающий авторитетов.** определение обособлено точкой, а не запятой - все дело в многозначности точки, - так и тире может выполнять дополнительную роль. Принять за ограничитель оборота можно и тире, когда оно необходимо по правилам.

Кстати, тире отделяет всегда части предложения, так что частью определения нигилист казаться не может.

Из справочника выше правило: *"Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении ставятся в качестве единого знака: 1)перед главным предложением, которому предшествует ряд однородных придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение сложного целого на две части"* будет простым.

Тогда не будет вопроса, нужна ли запятая перед тире в предложении

**Пусть живу я и не знаю, любишь или нет, − это лучше, чем признавшись, слышать нет в ответ.**